# How to use %union and fix "Semantic value used inside actions but has not declared the type" warning

Tags: compilation, bison, semantics, lex

I have `YYSTYPE` defined in `parser.hpp` file for **`scanner.lex` use**:

```
// parser.hpp
#define YYSTYPE Atom

typedef struct Atom
{
  int i_value;
  TypeEnum e_type;
  string *str_value;
  Node *node;
} atom_t;
```

In `parser.ypp` I'm getting an error on `RetType`

> "Semantic value used inside actions but has not declared the type"

```
RetType:
    Type                            {}
    |   VOID                        {
      debugPrint("Here");
      $$.e_type = TYPE_VOID;
    }
;
```

I want to get rid of the error and use `%union` but couldn't figure out how to:

```
// 
%union {
  struct atom_t atom;
}

%type <atom> RetType;
```

Comment: Why do you want to use `%union`? If you use `%union`, you cannot use `#define YYSTYPE`. But then, you shouldn't use that anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should not be using

```
#define YYSTYPE Atom
```

And if you do so, you will not be able to use `%union` (or any of the other ways bison provides to declare the semantic type), because putting a `#define YYSTYPE` into an external header file completely bypasses bison's attempt to set the semantic type itself.

What you should instead do is use

```
%define api.value.type { Atom }
```

in your bison prologue. That will copy the declaration of `YYSTYPE` into the bison-generated header, so you don't need to worry about it in your own header files.

Of course, that assumes that you are content for all terminals and non-terminals to use the same semantic value type, so that there is no need to use `%type` at all. However, bison allows you to use `%type` declarations in conjunction with `api.value.type` declarations, with the proviso that if you use a `%type` declaration anywhere, you must use it for all grammar symbols whose value is referenced (which is the same as the requirement for a grammar which uses the `%union` declaration).

If you declare `%type <atom>` for a particular grammar symbol, then bison translates any reference to that symbol's semantic value (`$$` or `$n`, depending on whether the symbol is on the left- or right-hand side of the `:`) into what would effectively be `$$.atom`. It's a simple textual substitution, since bison doesn't know anything about the semantic type itself, and it doesn't require that the selector be a simple word; you could, if you wanted to, use `%type <atom.node>`, in which case all references to those symbols' values would have `.atom.node` appended to them. That's not usually very useful outside of unions, because you no longer have any way of referring to the base value, but you might have a use case which fits.